# R: How to accurately overlay two plots in the same x-y grid?

Tags: r, plot

I would like to overlay two plots using base R.

Even though I have set the same `xlim`, `ylim` and `asp`, but the two plots cannot be accurately overlaid.

How can I do it?

Below is my example:

```r
image(t(volcano)[ncol(volcano):1,])
par(new = TRUE)
plot(1, 
     type = "n",
     xlim = c(par()$usr[1], par()$usr[2]),
     ylim = c(par()$usr[3], par()$usr[4]),
     asp = par()$asp,
     col.axis = "red"
)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you need a full plot? with just `image(..)`, no `par(new=TRUE)`, then add `points(0.5,0.5)`, I get a point added to the volcano plot.

Comment: I think it would help if you explained your follow-on plot needs. For instance, if it's just `points(..)` then you don't need `par(new=TRUE)`. If you need different scales, different axis options (and choose to have double-double-axes), or something else that cannot be done in an _additive_ way, then perhaps `par(new=TRUE)` is the only path.

Comment: And for the record, adding `points(.)` does _not_ hide the heatmap. `plot(..)` will hide it, `points(..)`/`lines(..)` will not, other plot-functions may not as well.

Comment: @r2evans, sorry I see what you mean. what I want to do is to make another empty plot with the same grid as the `image` object, then I can select region of interest on the empty plot and eventually get the x and y locations of the `image` object.

Comment: @r2evans, thanks for your help.  `points(..)` actually works very well, and I can use it to select the region of interest, and the x, y grid.